# How to filter array of dictionary data on based on user input in textfield

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, tableview

Hi I using the `array` **model data**, I load that data into `tableview`.

But I want to search that **data** based on user input in `textField`.

- Code.

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

               let model = array[indexPath.row]

                if let rate = model.price
                {
                    cell.pricelbl.text = "$" + rate
                }
                cell.namelbl.text = model.prodName ?? ""
      }

    //Textfield delegate methods.

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if textField == searchtextfield
            {
                var foundItems = [BaseApparel]()
                foundItems = self.array.filter { $0.prodName == searchtextfield.text! }
                self.array = foundItems

                self.searchtableview.reloadData()
            }
             return true
        }
```

Comment: what's the problem

Comment: it don't display any data in tableview when I try to text in text field.

Comment: set delegate and dataSource

Comment: Did you used searchbar for searching

Comment: no I using text field

Comment: Did you set the delegate for the textfield

Comment: Yes I give delegate property as self.

Comment: @srikanthkumar use this let foundItems = self.array.filter { $0. prodName.contains(searchtextfield.text!) }

Comment: No Amit it don't give any response in tableview

Comment: Did you use the code in the answer? were you able to get what you desired?@srikanthkumar

Answer (score 0):

Use predicates:
In viewDidLoad(), add the following line

```
searchtextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueDidModify(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Then use this function:

```
@objc func valueDidModify(_ sender:UITextField){
      let predicate =  NSPredicate(format:"self.prodName CONTAINS [cd] %@",sender.text)
      let filteredArray = self.array.filter{predicate. evaluateWithObject($0)}
     }
```

return numberOfRows as `filteredArray.count`